# Any public contracts / dApps that can execute multiswap?

Tags: uniswap, decentralized-exchange, arbitrage

Are there any smart contracts on ETH mainnet that can be used to execute e.g. arbitrage swap on single call? E.g. USDC -> DAI -> WETH -> USDC?

Or actually I'm more interested doing round-trip swaps: USDC -> DAI -> USDC. I've tried this on Uniswap Router V2 contract, but it does not work. I've seen MEVs/Bots with their own smart contract that can handle this kind of transactions, but just wondering if there's any readily available contracts that public can use? E.g. 1inch? dydx? AugustusSwap? (Those all provide somewhat bad documentations)

Thanks!

Comment: Have you dealt with this issue yet? pls share it with me